# Should I use separate locationManager for GPS and Network Provider? 

Tags: android, networking, gps, locationmanager

Can I use the same locationManager for requesting updates for the gps and network provider, or should I create two locationManagers and separate onLocation changed functions etc. I got really confused about this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to check and see which one is available in the order you want to use them and then use the corresponding one:

```
if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_TIME, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE, locationListener);
}
else if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)){
    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_TIME, LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE, locationListener);
}
```

You can use the same listener because all the listener's methods take as a parameter a `Location` object which is source agnostic:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // updateLocation();
}
```

Comment: Thank u, because I wanted to use this model for best performance (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) and so to decide what is the best location from several network and gps locations. Do you have any idea how I should implement the time window mentioned in this post? How to listen for updates for 2 min for example and then do sth...

Comment: When you call requestLocationUpdates() the second parameter is LOCATION_UPDATE_MIN_TIME, you can set this to 120000 (two mins)

Comment: Yes but the idea was to have the update min time set for about 15 sec for example, so in a period of 2 min, I would have about 4 locations (if everything goes by the clock), and from that 4 locations with the function provided in this post (isBetterLocation was the name i think) I would choose the most accurate one.. But I think I maybe have some other ideas, thanks for your reply anyway.